Low rank approximation to two matrices simultaneously
I'm trying to do a total-least squares-like regression but the set-up is slightly different and I end up with the following problem.
Let $C_1,\ C_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times (d+1)}$ where $n >> d$ and you can assume rank$(C_1) = $ rank$(C_2)= d+1$. Solve
$$ \min_{G: \text{rank($G$) = $d$}} ||C_1 - G||_F^2 + ||C_2 - G||_F^2.$$
I know that if there was only one term in the objective then doing SVD and setting the $d+1$ smallest singular value to zero would give me the answer but I do not know how to solve this. Is there a known solution to this? I am not too proficient with linear algebra.
I think I can settle for an approximate solution too.

This is equivalent to finding a rank $d$ approximation to the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{C_1 & C_2}
$$
Of the form $\pmatrix{G_1 & G_2}$, subject to the additional constraint that $G_1 = G_2$.  In other words, you're looking at a "structured low-rank approximation" (SLRA) problem. This is an area that has been well studied, I recommend looking for tools that fit your needs. This page has code that works in Matlab and Octave
